# User reputation list by posts reads "votes" when it should read "edits"

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, recent-activity

I am not sure, but this doesn't seems correct. My reputation by post and day reads "votes" when it should read "edits":
[image: edited]

I have edited "How can i disable Phone, SMS, Market and 3G functionality from Android two times in a row, but the reputation at the "+4" says line says it got it for votes?

Comment: Yep.  One of the devs should see this soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is now fixed. Probably long ago :-)